# Is there a word for a verb which requires an adverb or prep. phrase in order to make sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, adverbs, transitive-verbs, prepositional-phrases

*Put* is the one I'm thinking of.  It is always transitive, but even with a direct object, it still makes no sense without an adverb or prepositional phrase.

> I put it *somewhere*.
>
> I put it *on the shelf*.
>
> I put it *down*.

But never:

> I put it.

Is there a word for this kind of verb, and can anyone think of more like this?

Comment: This seems similar to a [ditransitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb), but that's a verb that takes two objects and a subject.

Comment: @simchona: I think *ditransitive* is a lot more recent than *transitive* and *intransitive*. Maybe linguists just haven't got around to a category name for verbs that take one object and a "spatial locator phrase", or whatever else can follow (so far as I know as I write, this may be because there's only one verb in the category! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get all linguisticsy about it, we can talk about the generalization of how verbs work. In traditional grammar, we talk about verbs having subjects and objects and whether they are transitive or intransitive. If we generalize this, we can talk about verbs being a kind of function that takes arguments, where subjects and objects are examples of kinds of argument verbs can take. The number of arguments a verb takes is called its [valency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29). Intransitive verbs are *monovalent*, taking just one argument, the subject. Transitive verbs are *divalent*, taking two arguments, the subject and the object. There are more esoteric types like *avalent* verbs like *rain* which really take no argument (that is, the dummy pronoun *it* in “it’s raining” doesn’t refer to anything and so is not an argument, and is just the way English syntax forces all verbs to have a subject even if they are avalent). And *put*, the word from the original question, is *trivalent*, requiring not just a subject and an object, but also a location.

The different kinds of arguments a verb takes are called [thematic relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relations), and have names like **agent**, **experiencer**, **theme**, **patient**, and **location** (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relations) for definitions of all the different kinds of relations). Many verbs can take many different kinds of thematic relations as arguments, and the different combinations of arguments that a verb can take are called its [subcategorization frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcategorization_frame). The specific thematic relations that a particular verb requires in its subcategorization frames are called its *[theta roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_role)*, and verbs are said to *assign* theta roles. The verb *put* is exceptional in that its subcategorization frame assign three theta roles, including a location argument.

Comment: So _put_ is trivalent.  It seems as if all ditransitive verbs would also be considered  trivalent as well, would they not?

Comment: @drm65, yes ditransitive verbs and *put* are all trivalent, but ditransitive verbs have a subcategorization frame of <agent, patient, recipient> (=<subject, direct object, indirect object>) whereas *put* has a subcategorization frame of <agent, patient, location>

Comment: So there is no word whose definition _only_ includes <agent, patient, location> verbs.

Comment: @drm65 there may be—I just don't know it. It'd have be a pretty specialized word known only to other English syntacticians

Comment: @drm65 I'd say the tersest you could get would be "trivalent verb that subcategorizes for location"

Comment: That sounds very sophisticated.  I love it!